# Where should I post discoveries, share knowledge about a specific topic like programming?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm looking for a community that people can share knowledge about something, i.e. a new and faster algorithm. If this kind of community doesn't exist yet, would be a good idea a Stack Exchange about it.

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is a collection of *question* and *answer* sites.  It's a place where people ask a question, and get an answer.

That doesn't fit into the model of the site, so topicality problems aside, it wouldn't be able to be an SE site.

Comment: So it would be a discussion site with the same aspects

Comment: Well, that's not generally true. If OP can create a proper/on-topic question, then he can share his discovery as an answer.

Comment: @masterjohn12 But SE doesn't host discussion sites, it hosts question and answer sites.

Comment: @Tom As [they've clearly indicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299146/where-should-i-post-discoveries-share-knowledge-about-a-specific-topic-like-pro/299147?noredirect=1#comment972361_299147), they're looking for a *discussion* site, rather than to ask a question and get an answer.

Comment: The question would explain you discovery and the answers and comments section would be a debate about that discovery

Comment: @masterjohn12 And SE has determined not to have sites like that, and to instead have question and answer sites.

Comment: @Servy Ok :/, but what do you think about this idea?

Comment: @masterjohn12 There used to be a close reason for precisely that called "Not a real question".  It's no longer in the pick list (would fall under "Other") but using a question to explain (not ask) something, and answers and comments to debate (not answer or seek clarification of the question) does not conform to the focused Q&A model that works so well on SE sites and would still attract quick close and downvotes.

Comment: @PolyGeo There's still an appropriate close reason for it.  You could go with too broad, unclear, or primarily opinion based (in order of most applicable to least applicable).  You wouldn't need a custom close reason.

Comment: @Servy you're right - I jumped straight to the fallback without mentioning options that may apply before it is needed